# How do I install 'react-native-childprocess' into a react native project?

Tags: react-native

How would I install 'react-native-childprocess' into an expo react project? No matter what I try I get

[image]

I have tried npm installing it and it told me that (ignore different file locations recreating err msg, I am running the npm package install in the main directory of the project, the one with the app.js)[image]

its the same with and without the -g

I cant remember what install i tried but after one of them it suggested a --force or --devsomething install. I did the dev and it seemed to have worked but still vs code won't recognize the package. the project still built but crashed when it reached the part where I try to use it. After installing yarn it doesnt throw me the 2nd error when I use 'npm install react-native-childprocess' in the directory but it still isn't working.
Finally 'npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-childprocess' gives me [image]

its been 3 days, what am I doing wrong? I am new to react/node so could be basic.

Comment: In one of your screenshots, you are trying to install `react-native-child` instead of `react-native-childprocess`, so the error is expected. You also mention you are using expo - if you are using the managed workflow, you won't be able to add a third party package with native dependencies.

Comment: the 'react-native-child' was a typo recreating the problem. neither work. How am I supposed to implement this package?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using expo with a managed workflow, which does not work with third party native modules. `react-native-childprocess` has some native code for iOS and Android - see the ios/ and android/ folders inside the package - and so cannot be used with an expo managed workflow. The error you are seeing when the app crashes is likely `Native module cannot be null`?
Read more about this kind of setup in the documentation: https://docs.expo.io/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#managed-workflow

If you really need to use this package, you can 'eject' your app using `expo eject` creating a 'bare' workflow that allows you to use packages with native code, but requires more understanding of the iOS/Android side of things. Read more about it in the documentation: https://docs.expo.io/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow

Note: I have created a new project with expo using the Typescript template, and had no issues when installing with `yarn add react-native-childprocess`, as well as no issue with vscode complaining about a missing typescript declaration (note that even though it installs correctly, the package will not work with a managed expo workflow).

Comment: If its not to much can you tell me what versions you are running for Node,
react-native-cli, and Java SE development Kit?

Comment: Sure, if that helps: node v12.19.0, react-native-cli 4.13.0, openjdk 1.8.0_222

Comment: I uninstalled nodejs via windows apps & features, installed https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.19.0/node-v12.19.0-x64.msi, with chocolatey (This automatically updated python and installed visual studio 2017 and a few other things. I  missed this in my previous 5 installs) Python in cmd yeilds the version chocolatey installed 3.9.4, yet enviroment variables are set to 3.8.5. npm uninstall -g react-native-cli. npm install -g react-native. expo init StackOverFlow -> typescriptblank. Opened in vscode -> Terminal -> npm install react-native-childprocess. import {spawn,kill} from 'react-native-child' fails

Comment: As I've mentioned before, you will not be able to use `react-native-childprocess` with Expo unless you eject. I see that you are working on Windows - I have no experience with RN or expo on that platform, so there might be other issues that you encounter.